# How to avoid SSL issues when using proxpy?

Tags: python, selenium, ssl, proxy

I am trying to use [proxpy](https://github.com/yeukhon/proxpy) to monitor any requests made during a python-selenium test. The python code I use is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
PROXY = "0.0.0.0:9999"
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy":PROXY,
    "ftpProxy":PROXY,
    "sslProxy":PROXY,
    "proxyType":"MANUAL"
}
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.co.in")
driver.quit()
```

and I start the proxy as follows:

```
python proxpy/proxpy/proxpy.py -p 9999
```

When I run the python test script I get the following error:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 64667)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adietz/anaconda/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 596, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Users/adietz/anaconda/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 331, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Users/adietz/Projects/Invest/browsermob/proxpy/proxpy/core.py", line 56, in __init__
    SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, client_address, server)
  File "/Users/adietz/anaconda/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 652, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/adietz/Projects/Invest/browsermob/proxpy/proxpy/core.py", line 137, in handle
    res = self.doCONNECT(host, port, req)
  File "/Users/adietz/Projects/Invest/browsermob/proxpy/proxpy/core.py", line 188, in doCONNECT
    ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23, do_handshake_on_connect = False)
  File "/Users/adietz/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 933, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/Users/adietz/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 544, in __init__
    self._context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this? How can I avoid this error? How am I able to just monitor the requests and responses...?

On a Linux machine the error is equivalent:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 35348)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 596, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 331, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/home/adietz/Projects/Invest/browsermob-proxy/proxpy/proxpy/core.py", line 56, in __init__
    SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, client_address, server)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 652, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/adietz/Projects/Invest/browsermob-proxy/proxpy/proxpy/core.py", line 137, in handle
    res = self.doCONNECT(host, port, req)
  File "/home/adietz/Projects/Invest/browsermob-proxy/proxpy/proxpy/core.py", line 188, in doCONNECT
    ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23, do_handshake_on_connect = False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 933, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 544, in __init__
    self._context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem with proxpy itself.
I checked the Github page and the last update is from four years ago.
If you are able to switch proxies I would suggest using Browsermob, it's very user friendly.
Since you are using python I found a wrapper library from a famous Selenium contributer: https://github.com/AutomatedTester/browsermob-proxy-py

Comment: That is one of the possibilities but it is also used to manipulate your traffic.

Comment: @DanielJ.Anderson I tried using browsermob for many hours, did not get it to work. That is why I am taking this approach...

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to resolve the cert error of proxpy mentioned in your question, but still failed to proxy https request.

If what you need is a proxy for examination of HTTP traffic, [mitmproxy](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/latest/mitmproxy.html) is a handy tool and best of the breed.

Comment: I just want to monitor the connections that are being made when opening a web page. Because a web page does not usually make connection with just one service, but uncountable. I want to find out WHAT connections are being made. The content of the requests/response are not really of interest to me, and I also do not want to change any of the transmitted content. I want to have it merely a way to gain a list of connections, in order to iron out random repeating selenium test errors...

Comment: @Alex mitmproxy works well as a "monitor", give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the code of [pproxy](https://github.com/yeukhon/proxpy) source repository.

@Alex If you can make some changes to the code. I think it works.

Following are the changes I suggest.

In [core.py](https://github.com/yeukhon/proxpy/blob/master/proxpy/core.py)
In ProxyHandler Class init method change the peer initialization

From

```
self.peer = False
```

to

```
self.peer = True
```

Please resolve the certificate issue by creating a pem file of your target application. place it in certs directory. {{This point I am not clear about how to do it.}}. Kindly check with @Homewrecker.

> Reason for failure:

peer value is harcoded with false. So every time it tries to make a httpConnection what ever you provide.

[image: This Screenshot may help you navigate to the code]

Answer (score 0):

You can find plenty [http proxy packages on the Cheese Shop](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=HTTP+proxy&submit=search). If one does not work, just pick another one.

I am taking a random one with modern Python support, [pyproxy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=HTTP+proxy&submit=search), it looks like:

```
$ pyproxy --port=8888 --log-to-stderr
[I 180124 13:28:59 pyproxy:242] http server started on 127.0.0.1:8888
[I 180124 13:28:59 pyproxy:242] http server started on 127.0.0.1:8888
[I 180124 13:30:11 web:2064] 200 CONNECT www.google.co.in:443 (127.0.0.1) 223.28ms
[I 180124 13:30:11 web:2064] 200 CONNECT www.google.co.in:443 (127.0.0.1) 223.28ms
```

Having the client request as:

```
curl -v --proxy http://localhost:8888 https://www.google.co.in/
```

Also as @georgexsh mentioned, you can use [mitmproxy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mitmproxy). Note that it has a web GUI, [mitmweb](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/latest/mitmweb.html), which looks like:

[image: mitmweb]